# Spring Boot 2 OIDC (OAuth2) client / resource server not propagating the access token in the WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, keycloak, spring-oauth2

[Sample project available on Github](https://github.com/codependent/spring-boot-2-oidc-sample)

I have successfully configured two Spring Boot 2 application2 as client/resource servers against Keycloak and SSO between them is fine.

Besides, I am testing authenticated REST calls to one another, propagating the access token as an `Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN` header.

After starting Keycloak and the applications I access either http://localhost:8181/resource-server1 or http://localhost:8282/resource-server-2 and authenticate in the Keycloak login page. The HomeController uses a WebClient to invoke the `HelloRestController` `/rest/hello` endpoint of the other resource server.

```
@Controller
class HomeController(private val webClient: WebClient) {

    @GetMapping
    fun home(httpSession: HttpSession,
             @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient: OAuth2AuthorizedClient,
             @AuthenticationPrincipal oauth2User: OAuth2User): String {
        val authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
        println(authentication)

        val pair = webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8282/resource-server-2/rest/hello").retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Pair::class.java)
                .block()

        return "home"
    }

}
```

This call returns a 302 since the request is not authenticated (it's not propagating the access token):

```
2019-12-25 14:09:03.737 DEBUG 8322 --- [nio-8181-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
```

OAuth2Configuration:

```
@Configuration
class OAuth2Config : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    fun webClient(): WebClient {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction())
                .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun clientRegistrationRepository(): ClientRegistrationRepository {
        return InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(keycloakClientRegistration())
    }

    private fun keycloakClientRegistration(): ClientRegistration {
        val clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("resource-server-1")
                .clientId("resource-server-1")
                .clientSecret("c00670cc-8546-4d5f-946e-2a0e998b9d7f")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
                .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
                .authorizationUri("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/insight/protocol/openid-connect/auth")
                .tokenUri("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/insight/protocol/openid-connect/token")
                .userInfoUri("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/insight/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo")
                .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
                .jwkSetUri("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/insight/protocol/openid-connect/certs")
                .clientName("Keycloak")
                .providerConfigurationMetadata(mapOf("end_session_endpoint" to "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/insight/protocol/openid-connect/logout"))
                .build()
        return clientRegistration
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests { authorizeRequests ->
            authorizeRequests
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
        }.oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .logout { logout ->
                    logout.logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                }
    }

    private fun oidcLogoutSuccessHandler(): LogoutSuccessHandler? {
        val oidcLogoutSuccessHandler = OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository())
        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(URI.create("http://localhost:8181/resource-server-1"))
        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm setting a `ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction` in the `WebClient`. This is what I've seen debugging:

[image]

The SubscriberContext isn't setting anything because `authentication.getCredentials() instanceof AbstractOAuth2Token` is false. Actually it is just a String:

```
public class OAuth2AuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    ... 

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        // Credentials are never exposed (by the Provider) for an OAuth2 User
        return "";
    }
```

What's the problem here? How can I automate the propagation of the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an out of the box solution for pure OAuth2/OIDC login applications, I've created a [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7771) for this.

In the meantime, I've created a specific `ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction` that retrieves the access token from the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`.

This is my custom solution:

```
    @Autowired
    lateinit var oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository: OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository

    @Bean
    fun webClient(): WebClient {
        val servletBearerExchangeFilterFunction = ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction("resource-server-1", oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository)
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(servletBearerExchangeFilterFunction)
                .build()
    }

    ...

    private fun keycloakClientRegistration(): ClientRegistration {
        return ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("resource-server-1")
                ...
```

```
const val SECURITY_REACTOR_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES_KEY = "org.springframework.security.SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES"

class ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction(private val clientRegistrationId: String,
                                          private val oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository: OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository?) : ExchangeFilterFunction {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    override fun filter(request: ClientRequest, next: ExchangeFunction): Mono<ClientResponse> {
        return oauth2Token()
                .map { token: AbstractOAuth2Token -> bearer(request, token) }
                .defaultIfEmpty(request)
                .flatMap { request: ClientRequest -> next.exchange(request) }
    }

    private fun oauth2Token(): Mono<AbstractOAuth2Token> {
        return Mono.subscriberContext()
                .flatMap { ctx: Context -> currentAuthentication(ctx) }
                .map { authentication ->
                    val authorizedClient = oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository?.loadAuthorizedClient<OAuth2AuthorizedClient>(clientRegistrationId, authentication, null)
                    if (authorizedClient != null) {
                        authorizedClient.accessToken
                    } else {
                        Unit
                    }
                }
                .filter { it != null }
                .cast(AbstractOAuth2Token::class.java)
    }

    private fun currentAuthentication(ctx: Context): Mono<Authentication> {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(getAttribute(ctx, Authentication::class.java))
    }

    private fun <T> getAttribute(ctx: Context, clazz: Class<T>): T? { // NOTE: SecurityReactorContextConfiguration.SecurityReactorContextSubscriber adds this key
        if (!ctx.hasKey(SECURITY_REACTOR_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES_KEY)) {
            return null
        }
        val attributes: Map<Class<T>, T> = ctx[SECURITY_REACTOR_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTES_KEY]
        return attributes[clazz]
    }

    private fun bearer(request: ClientRequest, token: AbstractOAuth2Token): ClientRequest {
        return ClientRequest.from(request)
                .headers { headers: HttpHeaders -> headers.setBearerAuth(token.tokenValue) }
                .build()
    }

}
```