# Default Authentication not set for Spring Webclient

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm configuring a spring application to use existing authentication in Webclient:

**Flow:**

Client login app -> service1 -> service2

**Webclient service1:**

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
                           OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
    
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
    
    oauth2Client.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
    
    return WebClient.builder()
            .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration()) 
            .baseUrl("some_url")
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                    .codecs(configurer ->
                            configurer.defaultCodecs()
                                    .maxInMemorySize(2 * 1024)
                    )
                    .build())
            .filter(this.logRequest())
            .build();
}
```

**service1 Call to service2:**

```
        Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = webClient
            .get()
            .uri("some_uri")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

    DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, Paths.get(joiner.toString()) , StandardOpenOption.CREATE).share().block();
```

The above fails to add a bearer token to the request, which subsequently fails auth on service2.

I can add the following to my Webclient:
`oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("keycloak");`
This will add a token to each request, but the token is not the existing token available at: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

It appears to be a newly requested token using the `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration` config in the application.properties

I've been able to get the existing token added to my request, by modifying the call to set the header as follows:

```
Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = webClient
            .get()
            .uri(Constant.AQUAMIS_DOCUMENTS_URL + entityId)
            .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getTokenString()))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
```

I'm unable to get the Webclient to use the existing token, without extracting it from Springs security context and explicitly setting it myself on the Webclient.

Am I missing something, from the documentation I've read my intial configuration should be reusing the token contained within the spring security context?

Comment: did you read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.0-RC1/reactive/oauth2/client/authorized-clients.html#oauth2Client-webclient-webflux

Comment: I have read the documentation,I'm using OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, rather than   ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, this is the only difference I can see, should it not work with my configuration also?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing [`.filter(new ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction())`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/bearer-tokens.html#_bearer_token_propagation)?

Comment: Here is an description of why this approach does not work: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7771

I am using ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction as apposed to ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction as described in the above issue, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Are you in a reactive or srvlet app? did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66586903/619830?